# Correct words to express that a computer system is not working

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

So when the computer hangs, there are a lot of ways to communicate it:

1. My system just got hanged   (Not sure if this sounds correct)
2. My system froze
3. My system is freezing
4. It got frozen
5. There is a freeze

I am not sure if the above is correct, although I checked the dictionary, and it seems the
The following sentences should be valid:

1. There was a freeze when I clicked on the button

I need some input on the above sentences, which are correct, which are not, and what could
be a more appropriate word to use.

Comment: The past participle _hanged_ is only used of death by hanging - otherwise it's _hung_.

Comment: "Hang" and "freeze" typically describe slightly different things: whether the display stops responding or the entire computer stops running and falls over.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably say:

- the system *is hanging* if it has slowed to a crawl (maybe something is moving on screen but it is not responding properly to user input)
- the system *froze*/*is frozen* if absolutely nothing is happening on the screen and user input has no effect
- the system *crashed* if it experienced a problem that caused it to shut down unexpectedly

Answer (score 0):

All of the sentences you gave are slightly wrong and sound off, best use the below

> My screen/computer hung

> My screen/computer froze

> When I clicked a button, my screen/computer froze

Comment: 'My screen/computer hanged' - surely it hung?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey My bad thanks for pointing my mistake out, is it possible to use "system hung" here

Comment: Suggestion: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22if+your+system+hung%22

Comment: "My computer died," is also commonly used.